# why this regex match whitespace also?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below regex

```js
const stringPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*";

const stringRegex = new RegExp(stringPattern, "g");

const str = "there are 33 states and 7 union territory in india.";

const matches = str.match(stringRegex);
console.log({matches});
```

why does this result contains whitespaces also while in the regex, have not used `\s` or  . and how do we exclude whitespace ?

```js
[
    "there",
    "",
    "are",
    "",
    "33",
    "",
    "states",
    "",
    "and",
    "",
    "7",
    "",
    "union",
    "",
    "territory",
    "",
    "in",
    "",
    "india",
    "",
    ""
]
```

Comment: The result does not contain any whitespace results. Those are all empty strings. The regular expression is continuing from the place that the last match finished and tries to match a space which matches the expression as it's attempting to match zero or more instances of alphanumeric characters.

Comment: if you don't want the empty string matches, change `*` (zero or more) to `+` (one or more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the `*` which is a quantifier that allows for zero occurrences, meaning it can also match empty strings, change it to `+` which is quantifier for one or more occurrences of the preceding element

```js
const stringPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"; 
const stringRegex = new RegExp(stringPattern, "g");
const str = "there are 33 states and 7 union territory in india.";
const matches = str.match(stringRegex);
console.log({ matches });
```